# Comparing two unrelated counts in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two boolean values, and I want to divide their counts.

Say a table has 1 yes value in column X and 2 yes values in column Y.
I want SELECT Count(X)/Count(Y) to return .5 .

The solutions I have found online use `WITH`, which `MS-Access`s is not allowing me to use.

Here is what I had using the `WITH` for more clarification:

```
WITH T2 AS
(SELECT GRANTS.[Grant Program Number] AS GPN, Count(GRANTS.[Grant Awarded]) AS AwardCount
FROM GRANTS
WHERE GRANTS.[Grant Awarded]=Yes)
SELECT (T2.AwardCount) / (T1.SubCount) AS [Award Rate]
FROM (SELECT GRANTS.[Grant Program Number] AS GPN, Count(GRANTS.[Grant Submitted]) AS SubCount 
FROM GRANTS 
WHERE GRANTS.[Grant Submitted]=Yes) AS T1 INNER JOIN GRANTS ON T1.GPN = T2.GPN
GROUP BY [Award Rate];
```

Comment: Instead of making us guess or infer the table structure, how about giving it to us? I'm lazy.

Comment: I did give it to you. Assume a table of two boolean columns named X and Y.

Comment: ...then the answer you selected is incorrect, isn't it? It doesn't mention X or Y.  :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the award rate for the whole table, then the query would be

```
SELECT
    SUM(IIF([Grant Awarded],1,0))/ NZ(SUM(IIF([Grant Submitted],1,0)),1) as [Award Rate]
FROM  
    GRANTS
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I don't have access so this might not work. Perhaps it will give you some idea anyhow:

```
select (1.0 * count( case when X = 'yes' then 1 end )) 
            / count( case when Y = 'yes' then 1 end ) 
from T;
```

If X and Y are booleans:

```
select (1.0 * count( case when X then 1 end )) 
            / count( case when Y then 1 end ) 
from T;
```

You can try this:

```
select (1.0 * sum( IIf(X, 1, 0))) 
            / sum( IIf(Y, 1, 0)) 
from T;
```

Comment: I tried by I get a syntax error for a missing operator. It's having a problem with me using "when" so I'm assuming I'm not allowed.

Comment: I googled and `sum(IIf(X, 1, 0)` appears to be what people are using. I'll update my answer